# Char pointer values changing in loop, but not after

Tags: c, string, pointers

I am currently confused about the execution of my basic c program to reverse a string. I use pointers. Keep in mind that my procedure is most definitely not the most efficient, I simply want to experiment pointers.
The problem I have is the following:

```
// initialize variables
char *sentence = malloc(256);
char *answer = malloc(256);

// ask user for input
printf("please enter sentence\n");
scanf("%s", sentence);

// loop to reverse the "sentence" string
    for (int index = count; index >=0; index--) // count has been determined as the length of the string "sentence" previously
{
    reversed = &sentence[index]; // pointer reversed points to last location of pointer sentence
    printf("\n ** %c", *reversed);
    reversed++; // incremend reversed by 1
}
printf("\n%s", reversed); // prints the cahr pointer reversed as string
```

[Console result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sdij.png)
If you cannot open the image, what I get is all the character printed in reverse order in the printf in the loop. However the final printf gives a weird result: ( If my sentence is bonjour) \n
** r
** u
** o
** j
** n
** o
** b
.
onjour <-- This is what I don't understand.

Thank you for your help, very appreciated.

Comment: Your question is not complete. I miss declaration and initialization of `count` and I miss declaration of `reversed`. Please add this information.

Comment: Why use `malloc` on such small strings.  Use `char reveresed[256];` instead.  It avoids memory leaks too.

Answer (score 2):

The code that prints the string character-by-character in reverse does not store the result in the answer. You need to do it by first pointing `reversed` to `answer`, and then adding characters to it as you progress through your loop:

```
char *reversed = answer;
for (int index = count; index >=0; index--) {
    *reversed = sentence[index];
    printf("\n ** %c", *reversed);
    reversed++;
}
*reversed = '\0';
printf("\n%s", answer);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
reversed = &sentence[index];
```

That's wrong, I think.

```
reversed = sentence[index];
```

would be right. Anyway that code is messy everywhere.